# Cómo paso este select inner join a código laravel por medio del controlador?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

```
SELECT * FROM maestros INNER JOIN grades ON maestros.grade_id = grades.id
```

segun lo pide asi laravel pero no me sale?

```
$users = 'DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
            ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
            ->get();
```

busco como paso este inner join a laravel por favor para el controller

Comment: tienes definidas las relaciones de Eloquent?

Comment: esa comilla simple en el DB esta de mas, por otro lado tu consulta SQL no se parece a la que tratas de escribir con Laravel, me causa duda

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia, lo que se debe realizar es:

```
$users = 'DB::table('users as a')
            ->join('contacts as b', 'a.id', '=', 'b.user_id')
            ->join('orders as as c', 'a.id', '=', 'c.user_id')
            ->select('b.phone', 'c.price')->get();
```

Para los campos de la tabla users deben ser especificados, no aceptada un * en la busqueda, tendras que hacer a.nombre, b.apellido, etc..